# Repackaging C types causes type cast error in Go

Tags: go, casting, package, cgo

I'm trying to repackage some go code that integrates with an existing C library.

The following works perfectly.

File 1:

```
package avcodec

type Codec C.struct_AVCodec
```

File 2:

```
package avformat

//#cgo pkg-config: libavformat libavcodec
//#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
//#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
import "C" 
import (    
"unsafe" 
) 

type Codec C.struct_AVCodec

func (s *FormatContext) AvFormatGetVideoCodec() *Codec {    
  result := C.av_format_get_video_codec((*C.struct_AVFormatContext)(s))
  return (*Codec)(result) // <- This works. Codec is defined in this package.
}
```

If I try to reference or move Codec from *File 2* into a separate package (eg. *File 1*) I get the error:

**cannot convert (func literal)((*C.struct_AVFormatContext)(s)) (type *C.struct_AVCodec) to type *Codec**

For example, this fails:

```
package avformat

//#cgo pkg-config: libavformat libavcodec
//#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
//#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
import "C" 
import (    
"avcodec"
"unsafe" 
) 

func (s *FormatContext) AvFormatGetVideoCodec() *avcodec.Codec {    
 result := C.av_format_get_video_codec((*C.struct_AVFormatContext)(s))      
 return (*avcodec.Codec)(result) // <- This fails. Codec defined in avcodec.
}
```

This also fails:

```
package avformat

//#cgo pkg-config: libavformat libavcodec
//#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
//#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>    
import "C" 
import ( 
"avcodec"   
"unsafe" 
) 

type Codec avcodec.Codec

func (s *FormatContext) AvFormatGetVideoCodec() *Codec {    
  result := C.av_format_get_video_codec((*C.struct_AVFormatContext)(s))
  return (*Codec)(result) // <- This also fails. Codec is based on avcodec.Codec.
}
```

I'd like to:

1. Understand why it fails, and
2. Identify how I can change the packaging so that the function uses the `Codec` type that is defined in the `avcodec` package.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a lot going on in that one line. I would suggest trying each piece by one to see which one fails.

Comment: The error is happening on the return. I've simplified the code to highlight the casting error. Everything else works :)

Comment: What is the definition of `avcodec.Codec `? If you're defining a Go type, you only need to define it in once place. Types are not aliases, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do by defining `Codec` in each package.

Comment: @JimB Looks like that redefinition was just as an experiment.

Comment: Even with the type redefinitions I can't replicate the failure. What we need is a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at this. I've found a workable solution. @JimB the problem pops-up when you are using C imports. Nonetheless, thanks for trying.

Comment: @haroldcampbell: yes, I understand the C types can differ slightly, especially when the C type is a typedef. You also should be able to convert these types if everything is declared correctly. I fail to see the benefit to the solution below at all though, since if you're gong to accept an `interface{}`, what's the point of defining the extra types at all?

Comment: @JimB: I use the `Codec` type elsewhere in the program, and do require the underlying `C.struct_AVCodec` for several methods. By using the type assertion, I'm in essence solving the problem of accepting and forcing a check that the underlying type is `C.struct_AVCodec` (eg. in the `AvformatNewStream(...)` method below. I'll agree that this solution with the `interface{}` is not prettiest, but I haven't been able to find a better solution.

Comment: @JimB: I've updated the question to make it adhere to Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Hopefully you'll be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @haroldcampbell: I think I see what you're trying to do now. Yes, a `C.struct_AVCodec` defined in one package is a different type than a `C.struct_AVCodec` defined in another, so converting between them doesn't work. If you want to be able to covert that to an `avcodec.Codec` from within other packages, you need to use `unsafe`, or just use the C types directly throughout. The C type system is not the Go type system, and manual conversions are often necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was failing due to how Go represents types.

For instance, given:

```
//Ex1
package avformat 
//.. deleted for simplicity

type Codec C.struct_AVCodec
```

...and

```
//Ex2
package avcode 
//.. deleted for simplicity

type Codec C.struct_AVCodec
```

In the code above, the `C.struct_AVCodec` in ex1 is different from the `C.struct_AVCodec` in ex2, even though the same are lexically the same.

Specifically, the fully qualified type in ex1 is `avformat._Ctype_struct_AVCodec`, while ex2 is `avcodec._Ctype_struct_AVCodec`

This explains why the functions in the `package avformat` that were trying to cast anything from an external type (in this case from `package avcodec`) to the local `C.struct_AVCodec` were failing.

## Solution

To get this to work, I relied on type assertions.

```
package avformat

func (s *FormatContext) AvformatNewStream(c avcodec.ICodec) *Stream {
  v, _ := c.(*C.struct_AVCodec)
  return (*Stream)(C.avformat_new_stream((*C.struct_AVFormatContext)(s), (*C.struct_AVCodec)(v)))
}
```

...and

```
package avcodec

type ICodec interface{}
```

Comment: Excellent answer about how things work in the innards of `cgo`. I'm definitely going to remember this gotcha.